Flutter flutter_flavorizr overwrite the existing flavor settings
I use flutter_flavorizr for create a the flavors in flutter, when I try to create a flavor, the existing flavors code will be overwrited by the command "flutter pub run flutter_flavorizr", is any possible to avoid overwrite the existing flavors settings? just focus on the new add?
thanks
run "flutter pub run flutter_flavorizr" but overwrite the existing code.
